# Display headers using vimdiff or vim -d

Tags: shell-script, vim, vimdiff

I have 2 tables which I need to compare and display the differences. I am able to do that using the following command:

```
vim -d table1 table2 -c :TOhtml -c :wqa
```

The problem I am facing is it's excluding the headers and captions when doing the vimdiff. Can someone show me a way how to display the headers and captions/titles of the columns together with the differences?

I am looking for something like:

```
S.No Name Zipcode       S.No Name Zipcode
11   abc  75000         11   aabc 75000
12   def  85000         13   def  85000
```

Comment: try (echo "S.No  Name  Zipcode   S.No  Name  Zipcode" &&vim -d table1 table2 -c :TOhtml -c :wqa) ? At least it looks like it has headers.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the following function, in your .bashrc or the command line:

```
mydiff () { 
vimdiff $1 $2    +'1sp
                   se noscb
                   winc l
                   1sp
                   se noscb
                   winc h
                   winc j'
}
```

Explanation :

- `1sp` : creates a split
- `se noscb` : set noscrollbind for the newly created window
- `winc l` : go the window on the right
- `1sp` : do a screen split
- `se noscb` : set noscrollbind for the newly created window
- `winc h` and `winc j` : go back to the first window

then just call the function as follows:

```
mydiff table1 table2
```